# How to render params in view via JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to render JSON to print the page. It's a method that it updates an attribute and render a view to print, like this:

```
class Admin::RequestsController < Admin::ApplicationController

  def print
    @request.print = 1
    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save
        format.json { render json: @request.as_json(only: [:id, :number]) }
      end
    end
    authorize @request
  end

end
```

This way, after clicking on the print icon, it opens a new window with options to print, but it lists nothing. Only `[Object object]`.

I'm trying this to render `print.json.builder` to print, but it doesn't work:

```
json.(@request, :id, :number)
json.items do |json|
  json.(@request.items, :item, :request_product)
end
```

I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what kind of information is in `@request` and what you expect the json to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing `authorize @request` at the end of your method?

Ruby implicitly returns whatever the last line of your method is, so you want your `format.json` method call to be the last thing you do. Could you move the authorize to be the first method call?

If it does need to be at the end, you can try this:

```
def print
    @request.print = 1
    result = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save
        result = format.json { render json: @request.as_json(only: [:id, :number]) }
      end
    end
    authorize @request

    result
  end
```

Comment: It's an action method, not a model method

Comment: I know it's not necessary, but I think this should not interfere in the final result.